# CakePHP 2.5 Basic Search different controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am writing a website application in CakePHP, I have the requirement to have a search box on the homepage (pages/home.ctp, PagesController) that searches content from my Events page (Events/index.ctp, EventsController).

I want the search to look in all fields of the events table but only have the one input box.

When a user clicks search or hits enter they should be taken to the Events/Index.ctp page where the events are all listed.

1. Is this possible? if so could I get some pointers?
2. If not how can i achieve something similar?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: It sounds like you recently started creating that application. Why not choose CakePHP 3?

Comment: @AndreSantiago I havent used CakePHP 3 as i have a Base CakePHP Application with all the authentication etc already built in for 2.5, the plugin i used for authentication is not on 3.0 yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual search should be done in a model, since that's the layer that you use to retrieve data.  So if you're searching events, you'll put a `search()` method in your Event model.

Then, in ANY controller, you can access that `search()` method.  Which controller you do that in depends on any number of things that only you can take into account.

If you're in the Events Controller:

```
$this->Event->search($postData);
```

If you're in a different (but associated) Controller:

```
$this->User->Event->search($postData);
```

If you're in a different (non-associated) Controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Event');
$this->Event->search($postData);
```

Based on your description, it sounds like you'd just want to make your form post to the Events Controller's `index()` method, where you can check if there was a search query submitted, and if there was, run the search.